# using myproject/.npmrc with registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

How do I setup a .npmrc file inside my project where I can define my own private registry? I don't want to have this kind of configuration in my user config .npmrc. Every other developer should be able to just `git clone` the project and run `npm install`.

This is what I have so far:

```
// .npmrc
registry=https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/me/

// package.json:
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.2.3",
    "myPrivateLibFromNpmFury": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

`npm install myPrivateLibFromNpmFury`

returns

`npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/myPrivateLibFromNpmFury`

Comment: That works fine for me. Make sure your `.npmrc` is at the root of your project

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As it was pointed out by @Paulpro and @Alexey B. the most parts of it worked already, but I couldn't see it right away, maybe because I didn't reload my bash environment properly. But after that I faced other issue with `npm outdated` that was caused by the registry url. It turns out npm can only have one registry url, (which is pretty crazy) and if you want to use private and public npm-modules you have to proxy the public npm-module registry through your private registry. Luckily fury.io supports that, so in my case instead of using this:

```
//.npmrc
registry=https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/me/
```

i have to use this:

```
//.npmrc
registry=https://npm-proxy.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/USER_NAME/
```

**UPDATE**:
It is possible to work around the problem (npm is tied to only one registry). First you have to add a [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry) to all of your private packages.
Now with `.npmrc` you can link the registries for the scopes, and you no longer need any proxies at all.

```
//.npmrc
@project_a:registry=https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/USER_NAME/
@project_b:registry=https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/USER_NAME/
@company_a:registry=https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/USER_NAME/
```

Comment: To me, what I was needing was @scope:registry=file:libraries/ to look for packages in scope into a directory I had in my monoRepository.

Answer (score 20):

Noticed to the docs

> **Per-project config file**
>
> When working locally in a project, a .npmrc file in the root of the
>   project (ie, a sibling of node_modules and package.json) will set
>   config values specific to this project.
>
> Note that this only applies to the root of the project that you're
>   running npm in. It has no effect when your module is published. For
>   example, you can't publish a module that forces itself to install
>   globally, or in a different location.

I tried to create the files you specified in the question(package.json and .npmrc), everything working fine. Maybe you made a typo somewhere?

```
frgt$ npm i myPrivateLibFromNpmFury --verbose

npm info using npm@3.3.12
npm info using node@v5.1.1
npm verb request uri https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/me/myPrivateLibFromNpmFury
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 14:36:10
npm verb request id 23f09acc4e7021c7
npm http request GET https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/me/myPrivateLibFromNpmFury
npm http 403 https://npm.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/me/myPrivateLibFromNpmFury
```

Comment: yes indeed it works, maybe i just didnt reload the bash session when i setup this, i have a different issue now: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11122
can you try `npm outdated` on your machine?

Comment: its a fake oauth token in the issue

Comment: of course, its a fake, but .npmrc config loaded. i thought thats was the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the seamless proxy:

```
registry=https://npm-proxy.fury.io/AUTH_TOKEN/me/
```

Comment: This resolved the problem for me. In my case, after fixed the format, the .npmrc get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating custom npm config for the project**

```
You can create .npmrc file in your project folder, creating .npmrc file override 
the default .npmrc which is located in C:\Users\username\.npmrc (it will work as global variable)


# for custom package from your companies artifactory
@myscope:registry=https://mycustomregistry.example.org

# if you want to override with default
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/
```